# CheckBoxFor is keeping checkbox checked despite the Model property being false, what do I need to check?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a simple user registration page with a simple Model that contains a boolean property for "User Accepts TOS". I have a server-side check upon Save action that checks to see if username is already taken or not, if it is taken then I add an error to the `ModelState` and set the `UserAcceptsTOS` boolean to false, and return the view by passing the same user object with `UserAcceptsTOS` set to false.

The issue is that the checkbox is rendered checked. I have Viewed the source to ensure no bootstrapping javascript is checking it, it is being actually rendered checked.

The following is my Razor checkbox declaration

```
@HTML.CheckBoxFor(model => model.UserAcceptTOS, new { @class = "form-element" })
```

I even set the breakpoint in the above code and saw the expression to be returning false but the checkbox rendered in HTML has `checked="checked"` in it. What else do I need to check? Here is more code

Model

```
public class User 
{
  public string Username { get; set; }
  public bool UserAcceptsTOS { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action

```
public ActionResult Register(User user) 
{
  if (UserNameTaken(user.Username)) 
  {
    ModelState.AddModelError("usernametaken", "Please choose a different username");
    user.UserAcceptsTOS = false;
  }

  return View(user);
}
```

Comment: Clear the previous value from the modelstate (you could `ModelState.Clear()` before you `AddModelError()`).  The ModelState keeps the previous values in case of an error so the user does not have to type in all the values they previously typed in because of a validation error.

Comment: I know you have said you have checked what is actually been returned but can you please put a break point after the bool is set to false and check if was actually set to false in the model that is returned.

Comment: @ErikPhilips That was it. Thank you :) I wish you could post this as an answer.

Comment: @fahadash I knew it was a duplicate problem, I just couldn't find the Q to duplicate it from.  Looks like CodeCaster found it.